CRUD con javascript y node
estoy haciendo un CRUD con javascript que se conecte a una base de datos mysql mediante node
Me ocurre un problema al darle click al modificar un producto.
code.js:99
   GET http://localhost:3000/api/articulos/16 404 (Not Found)

modificarArticulo @ code.js:99
(anonymous) @ code.js:62
code.js:153 Error al obtener el artículo para modificar: Error: La solicitud de obtener el artículo no fue exitosa. Código de estado: 404
at code.js:102:27
Paso el HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
  <!-- Default theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css"/>
  <title>Inventario</title>
  <style>
    body {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }
    table thead {
        background-color: #0a4f70;
        color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb - 5 bg-body rounded">
    <button id="btnCrear" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalArticulo">Crear</button>
    <table id="tablaArticulos" class="table mt-2 table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="modalArticulo" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Artículos</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="formArticulo">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-form-label">Descripción:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="precio" class="col-form-label">Precio:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="stock" class="col-form-label">Stock:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stock">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


La parte del code.js
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/articulos/';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const modalArticulo = document.getElementById('modalArticulo');
    if (modalArticulo) {
        const modalInstance = new bootstrap.Modal(modalArticulo);

        const btnCrear = document.getElementById('btnCrear');
        if (btnCrear) {
            btnCrear.addEventListener('click', () => {
                modalInstance.show();
            });
        }

        const formArticulo = document.getElementById('formArticulo');
        const descripcion = document.getElementById('descripcion');
        const precio = document.getElementById('precio');
        const stock = document.getElementById('stock');

        const btnGuardar = document.getElementById('btnGuardar');
        if (btnGuardar) {
            btnGuardar.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const nuevoArticulo = {
                    descripcion: descripcion.value,
                    precio: parseFloat(precio.value),
                    stock: parseInt(stock.value)
                };

                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(nuevoArticulo)
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                  
                    alert('Artículo guardado exitosamente.');
                    modalInstance.hide();                     cargarDatos(); 
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error en la solicitud Fetch:', error);
                    alert('Error al guardar el artículo. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
                });
            });
        }

 
        const tablaArticulos = document.getElementById('tablaArticulos');
        tablaArticulos.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            const target = event.target;
            if (target.classList.contains('eliminar-btn')) {
                const fila = target.closest('tr');
                const id = fila.id.split('-')[1]; 
                eliminarArticulo(id);
            } else if (target.classList.contains('modificar-btn')) {
                const fila = target.closest('tr');
                const id = fila.id.split('-')[1]; 
                modificarArticulo(id);
            }
        });
    }

    const tablaArticulos = document.getElementById('tablaArticulos');


    function cargarDatos() {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
    
            tablaArticulos.innerHTML = '';

 
            data.forEach(articulo => {
                const fila = document.createElement('tr');
                fila.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${articulo.id}</td>
                    <td>${articulo.descripcion}</td>
                    <td>${articulo.precio}</td>
                    <td>${articulo.stock}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary modificar-btn">Modificar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger eliminar-btn">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                `;
                fila.id = `articulo-${articulo.id}`;
                tablaArticulos.appendChild(fila);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error al cargar los datos:', error));
    }

    function modificarArticulo(id) {
        fetch(`${url}${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('La solicitud de obtener el artículo no fue exitosa. ' + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(articulo => {
        
                const descripcionInput = document.getElementById('descripcion');
                const precioInput = document.getElementById('precio');
                const stockInput = document.getElementById('stock');
    
                descripcionInput.value = articulo.descripcion;
                precioInput.value = articulo.precio;
                stockInput.value = articulo.stock;
   
                const modalInstance = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalArticulo'));
                modalInstance.show();
    
           
                const btnGuardar = document.getElementById('btnGuardar');
                btnGuardar.onclick = function () {
                    const datosModificados = {
                        descripcion: descripcionInput.value,
                        precio: parseFloat(precioInput.value),
                        stock: parseInt(stockInput.value)
                    };

                    fetch(`${url}${id}`, {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(datosModificados)
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            alert('Artículo modificado exitosamente.');
                            modalInstance.hide(); 
                            cargarDatos(); 
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('La solicitud de modificar el artículo no fue exitosa. Código de estado: ' + response.status);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error al modificar el artículo:', error);
                        alert('Error al modificar el artículo. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
                    });
                };
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error al obtener el artículo para modificar:', error);
                alert('Error al obtener el artículo para modificar. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
            });
    }

    function eliminarArticulo(id) {
        if (confirm('¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar este artículo?')) {
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/articulos/${id}`, { 
                method: 'DELETE',
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    const filaEliminar = document.getElementById(`articulo-${id}`);
                    if (filaEliminar) {
                        filaEliminar.remove();
                        alert('Artículo eliminado exitosamente.');
                    } else {
                        alert('No se pudo encontrar el artículo en la tabla.');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('Error al eliminar el artículo:', response.statusText);
                    alert('Error al eliminar el artículo. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error al eliminar el artículo:', error);
                alert('Error al eliminar el artículo. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
            });
        }
    }

    cargarDatos();
});


y este es el server.js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'none'; worker-src blob:;");
    next();
});


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'Articulos'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error al conectar a la base de datos MySQL:', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Conexión exitosa a MySQL');
});


app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


app.post('/api/articulos/', (req, res) => {
    const { descripcion, precio, stock } = req.body;

    const query = `INSERT INTO Articulos (descripcion, precio, stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
    connection.query(query, [descripcion, precio, stock], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error al guardar los datos en la base de datos:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error al guardar los datos');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Datos guardados correctamente en la base de datos');
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Datos guardados correctamente' }); 
    });
});

app.get('/api/articulos/:id', (req, res) =>{
    const query = `SELECT * FROM Articulos`;
    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error('Error al obtener los datos de la base de datos:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error al obtener los datos');
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json(result);
    });
});

app.put('/api/articulos/', (req, res) => {
    const articuloId = req.body.id;
    const { descripcion, precio, stock } = req.body;

    const query = `UPDATE Articulos SET descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ? WHERE id = ?`;
    connection.query(query, [descripcion, precio, stock, articuloId], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error al modificar el artículo en la base de datos:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error al modificar el artículo');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Artículo modificado correctamente en la base de datos');
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Artículo modificado correctamente' });
    });
});

app.delete('/api/articulos/:id', (req, res) => {
    const articuloId = req.params.id;

    const query = `DELETE FROM Articulos WHERE id = ?`;
    connection.query(query, [articuloId], (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.error('Error al eliminar el articulo de la base de datos:', err)
            res.status(500).send('Error al eliminar el articulo');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Articulo eliminado correctamente');
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Borrado correctamente'});
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor Node.js corriendo en el puerto 3000');
});


La verdad que ya me estoy volviendo loco con este error. Use chatgpt pero ni asi pude solucionarlo. Necesito su ayuda.
Gracias!

puede que el server se esté bindeando a 127.0.0.1, ::1 o la ip del interfaz, proba ponerlo explicito app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', ...  o app.listen(3000, 'localhost', ...  .-> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-app-listen-function/

No estas usando el ID al momento de obtener por ID, agrega:
const { id } = req.params;

y [id] acá:
connection.query(query, [id], (err, result)

Por otro lado, la conexión a tu base de datos debe ser asíncrona (async, await) y usando un try-catch. Te aconsejo separar el código en carpetas de helpers, middleware, base de datos, rutas, etc. así tendrás todo más organizado.

no explica el 404
